# how to have labels and input fields side by side in Reactjs and bootstrap forms

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

i have used Reactjs with bootstrap to have forms, however i couldn't have the labels and the input fields side by side.

i only want them to be side by side not under each other.

here is my code:

```
    const firstComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Form className="column justify-content-center page">
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
        <Form.Label>Benzersiz Ad</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
        <Form.Label>Görünen İsim</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
        <Form.Label>Oyun Açıklaması</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
        <Form.Label>Oyun Türü</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
        <Form.Label>Bireysel</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
        <Form.Label>Oyun Durumu</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
        <Form.Label>Açık</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default firstComponent
```

however, i have tried to style it in a different sheet but it couldn't be applied, also i tried the inline styling but it didn't work

any help is welcomed!